# How to I set logging for gunicorn GeventWebSocketWorker

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I have django rest framework application with socket.io. To run it in staging I use gunicorn as WSGI-server and GeventWebSocketWorker as a worker. The thing I want to fix is that there's no logs for web requests like this:

```
[2023-02-10 10:54:21 -0500] [35885] [DEBUG] GET /users
```

Here's my gunicorn.config.py:

```
worker_class = "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker"
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 1
log_level = "debug"
accesslog = "-"
errorlog = "-"
access_log_format = "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s '%(r)s' %(s)s %(b)s '%(f)s' '%(a)s'"
```

Here's the command in docker compose I use deploy app:

```
command:
  - gunicorn
  - my_app.wsgi:application
```

I saw the issue was discussed in gitlab: https://gitlab.com/noppo/gevent-websocket/-/issues/16 but still I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to the fact that the GeventWebSocketWorker is not capturing the web request logs, and thus they are not being printed in the gunicorn logs. One potential solution is to use a middleware that logs the requests before they are passed to the GeventWebSocketWorker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already configured your gunicorn settings to output debug-level logs, so it's possible that the logs you're looking for are being written to the console output or error stream rather than to a log file.

One thing you could try is redirecting the console output and error stream to log files using the --access-logfile and --error-logfile options, like this:

```
accesslog = "/path/to/access.log"
errorlog = "/path/to/error.log"
```

This will redirect the access and error logs to the specified files, rather than writing them to the console output. You can then check the log files to see if the debug-level logs are being written there.

Alternatively, you could try using a logging library like Python's built-in logging module to output more detailed logs. Here's an example configuration that might work for your use case:

```
import logging

# Create a logger with the name of your application
logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')

# Set the logging level to debug
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a stream handler to output logs to the console
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

# Add a formatter to the handler to format the log messages
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

You can place this code in a file called logging_config.py, and then import it in your Django settings file and add it to the LOGGING setting:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'my_app': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

This will configure the logger to output log messages with a timestamp, log level, and message to the console. You can then add logging statements in your Django views or other code to output debug-level logs when certain events occur:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')

def my_view(request):
    logger.debug(f'GET {request.path}')
    # ... rest of the view logic ...
```

This will output a log message like [2023-02-19 09:12:43,244] [DEBUG] GET /users when the view is accessed with a GET request.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `- --access-logfile=/path/to/access.log` parameter to your gunicorn command to write to a file or   `- --access-logfile=-` to write to stdout.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#accesslog